# Refactor code that repeats

Tags: c++, refactoring

I've got this class:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class QueryStatistics
{
    private:
        std::vector < std::pair <std::string,int >> queries_title;
        std::vector < std::pair <std::string,int >> queries_author;
        std::vector < std::pair <std::string,int >> queries_phrase;
        std::vector < std::pair <int,int >>     queries_id;

    public:
        QueryStatistics();
        virtual ~QueryStatistics();

        void increase_freq_title  (std::string & title);
        void increase_freq_author (std::string & author);
        void increase_freq_phrase (std::string & phrase);
        void increase_freq_id     (int id_doc);
};
```

And this bit of code reapeats itself 4 times, but with a different vector each time.

```
void QueryStatistics::increase_freq_title  (std::string & title)
{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < queries_title.size(); i++)
    {
        if (queries_title[i].first == title)
        {
            queries_title[i].second += 1;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I refactor this so as to avoid having to repeat the same code four times?

Comment: Why don't you create one function and add a parameter that takes a vector?

Comment: With a `template<class T> void increase_freq( std::vector< std::pair<T, int > >& v, T const& k )`, the body operating on `v` like your sample code does on `queries_title`.  I would make it a free function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would do it if making your own templates is an option.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void QueryStatistics::increase_freq  (T title, std::vector<U>& vec)
{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        if (vec[i].first == title)
        {
            vec[i].second += 1;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Since your vectors are private, you could have your four public member functions call the function above instead of repeating the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no need for the complex template parameter, just simple

```
#include <string>
    #include <vector>

    class QueryStatistics
    {
        private:
            std::vector < std::pair <std::string,int > > queries_title;
            std::vector < std::pair <std::string,int > > queries_author;
            std::vector < std::pair <std::string,int > > queries_phrase;
            std::vector < std::pair <int,int > >     queries_id;

        public:

            template<typename T, typename U>
            void increase(T& query, U const&  para)
            {
                for (unsigned int i=0; i < query.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (query[i].first == para)
                    {
                        query[i].second += 1;
                        return;
                    }
             }


            }

            void increase_freq_title  (std::string & title)
            {
                increase(queries_title,title);

            }
            void increase_freq_author (std::string & author)
            {
                  increase(queries_author,author);
            }
            void increase_freq_phrase (std::string & phrase)
            {
                increase(queries_phrase,phrase);
            }
            void increase_freq_id     (int id_doc)
            {
                increase(queries_id,id_doc);
            }
    };
```